# Deciding whether these functions are characteristic functions without Bochner's theorem

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

I want to decide for the following functions whether they are characteristic functions of a real-valued RV/probability measure on $\mathbb R$.
$$\varphi(t) = \frac13e^{-8t^2}+\frac23e^{2(e^{3it}-1-it)}$$
and
$$\psi(t) = \frac1{1+t^4}$$

I have already checked the basic properties $\varphi(-t)=\overline{\varphi(t)}$, $\varphi(0)=1$ and $\lvert\varphi\rvert\le 1$ for both functions, and they are both continuous.

I came across Bochner's theorem when looking for and approach to this problem. However, it is far beyond anything I have ever done and has never been introduced in any of my courses.

How can we (dis)prove that these functions are characteristic functions without Bochner's theorem?

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't know the boundary of "anything you've ever done", nor your courses, so it's hard to tell what help you may need. The first is quite obviously a mixture of a normal distribution and a scaled and shifted Poisson distribution, it *is* a characteristic function. The second one isn't, because it would mean that the first, second and third central moments would have to be zero, that's quite hard on a probability distribution.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Moments

Comment: @ProfessorVector Moment Generating Function had me confused there, sorry! Could you please expand a bit on "that's quite hard on a probability distribution"?

Comment: Well, what would $EX^2=0$ mean? $P(X=0)=1$, right? But then, the characteristic function would be $1$.